# Changing the position of div on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want an image to scroll up as I scroll down the page. I could do that quite easily, but the issue I'm having is that in the jQuery I'm changing the image's CSS, specifically its `transform` property. But I'm using the `transform` property already, to center align the image.

**Code:**

```
.planeImg {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background: url("../images/plane.png");
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index: 99;
    height: 80px;
    width: 300px;
}

$(window).on("scroll", function() {
    var wScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
    $('.planeImg').css({'transform' : 'translate(0px, -'+ wScroll /2 +'%)'})
});
```

So because I'm using the transform property to center align the image, the jQuery is buggering up the position of my image.

Comment: You're setting the horizontal translate to `0px` in your JavaScript. You can just replace that with `-50%` to keep the horizontal centering. Is the vertical centering an issue, too?

Comment: You should be using top/left/bottom/right (or margin, etc) for positioning the image not the transform property.

Comment: Thanks that worked @JonUleis

Comment: Do you know how to use this method to move the image horizontally rather than vertically?

Comment: @JonUleis could you create an answer from your comment so that the author may accept it as an answer to close this question? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the calculation of `wScroll` to make the scrolling of the image follow the scrolling of the page. Please, let me know if this helps.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LkkLkaho/)

javascript

```
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
  var wScroll = ($(this).scrollTop() / $(window).height()) + 50;
  $('.planeImg').css({
    'transform': 'translate(-50%, -' + (wScroll) + '%)'
  })
});
```

CSS

```
.planeImg {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: url("https://www.google.be/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png");
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  z-index: 99;
  height: 80px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

Comment: That works also, is there a way of moving the image horizontally rather than vertically?